# Why PHP Artisan Tinker kept showing null?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
┌──[root@jdoe]──[/home/jdoe/jdoe] 
└── cat .env | grep APP_URL
APP_URL=https://www.jdoe.com                                                                                                                     
┌──[root@jdoe]──[/home/jdoe/jdoe] 
└── php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.10.2 (PHP 7.3.11-0ubuntu0.19.10.3 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> env('APP_URL')
=> null
>>> env('APP_URL');
=> null
>>>
```

I support to see `https://www.jdoe.com`

## Someone want to explain this ?

Comment: Try `EXPORT APP_URL=https://www.jdoe.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try restart Tinker. Sometimes it saves state somehow, so I get used to restart if I change something somewhere
2. Try `php artisan optimize:clear`. I think that should resolve your problem because Laravel defenetly store some state in cache if you set some settings